# Retrieve data from database and display in text fields.

Tags: php

Please help me. I written a code but it is not working well.
I want to retrieve data from database and display text fields.
My Code is:

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title>Practice</title></head>
    <body align="center">
    <?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","address_db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
     ?>

     <form action="1.php" method="post">
    Name     <br><input type="text" name="name"       value="<?php echo $_GET['n']; ?>"><br>
    Address 1<br><input type="text"  name="address_1" value=""><br>
    Address 2<br><input type="text"  name="address_2" value=""><br>
    Address 3<br><input type="text"  name="address_3" value=""><br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Clear">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="submit" name="retrieve" value="Retrieve">
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $address_1=$_POST['address_1'];
    $address_2=$_POST['address_2'];
    $address_3=$_POST['address_3'];
    if(($name=='')||($address_1=="")||($address_2=="")||($address_3==""))
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Please fill all fields')</script>";
    exit();
    }
    else
    {
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO address_tbl (name,address_1,address_2,address_3)
    VALUES ('$name','$address_1','$address_2','$address_3')");
    echo "<script>alert('Your record successfull inserted into database...')</script>";
    exit();
    }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['retrieve']))
    {
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM address_tbl");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      { 
       $name=$row['name'];echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
       $add1=$row['address_1'];echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
       $add2=$row['address_2'];echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
       $add3=$row['address_3'];echo "<br>";echo "<br>"; 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  
window.open('1.php?n=$name','_self');  </script>"; 
      }  
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please help me. give me any hint that I can solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: What is not working well? In order for us to help you, you need to give more detail about what is not working.

Comment: Actually I want to get data from database and display in form fields when I am clicking on retrieve button. Thanks for giving me response.

Answer (score 1):

try this ,

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `1address_tbl` (`name`,`address_1`,`address_2`,`address_3`)
VALUES ('$name','$address_1','$address_2','$address_3')");
```

it should work fine now. it needs to include ( ` ) around the table names and column name to make sql work correctly. you left them out,

you replace this with yours.

Comment: Please include your explanation

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have your php in a seperate file called index.php with just php code then create a page called index.html.php in that page use a foreach loop to output data from the database its the most common and practical way of doing what your trying to do .